# Deduct values from DataFrame based on cumulative sum python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have DataFrame 1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'rohit', 'rohit'], 'amount': [1000, 500,200,500,150,120,100]})
```

have DataFrame 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['virat','rohit'], 'amount_paid': [1400,200]})
```

Name in df2 is unique. using amount_paid column in df2. start deducting value in ascending order and stop once amount_paid in df2 is completely utilized

excepted output

```
    name    amount
0   virat   0
1   virat   100
2   virat   200
3   virat   500
4   virat   150
5   rohit   0
6   rohit   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
s = (df1
 .groupby('name')['amount'].cumsum()
 .sub(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['amount_paid']))
)

df1['new'] = df1['amount'].mask(s.lt(df1['amount']), s.clip(lower=0))
```

Output:

```
    name  amount  new
0  virat    1000    0
1  virat     500  100
2  virat     200  200
3  virat     500  500
4  virat     150  150
5  rohit     120    0
6  rohit     100   20
```

Comment: tried the code but rohit values are not coming

Comment: what do you mean by "*are not coming*"? I posted the output given your reproducible input. It seems to match what you expect.

Comment: Can you comment on your feedback? Did it eventually work?