# Subract values from DataFrame based on cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame 1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'rohit', 'rohit'],
    'amount': [1000, 500, 200, 500, 150, 120, 100]})
```

and DataFrame 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['virat', 'rohit'],
    'amount_paid': [1400, 200]})
```

Name in dataframe2 is unique. Using amount_paid column in df2. start deducting value in ascending order and stop once amount_paid in df2 is completely utilized

excepted output

```
    name    amount_left   amount_used_to_knock_off
0   virat   0                1000
1   virat   100               400
2   virat   200                 0
3   virat   500                 0
4   virat   150                 0
5   rohit   0                 120
6   rohit   20                 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a slight variation of [my previous answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283143/16343464):

```
s = (df1
 .groupby('name')['amount'].cumsum()
 .sub(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['amount_paid']))
)

df1['amount_left'] = df1['amount'].mask(s.lt(df1['amount']), s.clip(lower=0))

df1['amount_used_to_knock_off'] = (df1['amount'].sub(s).clip(lower=0)
                                   .mask(s<0, df1['amount'])
                                   )
```

Output:

```
    name  amount  amount_left  amount_used_to_knock_off
0  virat    1000            0                      1000
1  virat     500          100                       400
2  virat     200          200                         0
3  virat     500          500                         0
4  virat     150          150                         0
5  rohit     120            0                       120
6  rohit     100           20                        80
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, amount_used_to_knock_off first row data should be 1000 not 1400.

Comment: @user15590480 see update, just a `mask` to add ;)

Comment: Thanks @mozway.

Can you please help here - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76808979/python-deduct-values-from-dataframe-based-on-cumulative-sum

Answer (score 0):

First, we take a groupby on name and calculate the cumulative sum of amount on df1 and also merge the df2 so we can compare cumulative amount vs. amount_paid. Then we subtract amount_paid by cumulative amount, depending on the result, we can make the following conclusions:

1. If the difference is positive, we've used the total amount in that row.
2. If the difference is negative but its magnitude is less than the amount, that means we only used a portion of the amount.
3. If the difference is negative but its magnitude is larger or equal to the amount, that means we had already paid off and none of the amount on that row was used.

After that, just some basic book keeping to get the desired columns.

```
out = df1.join(df1.groupby("name")["amount"].cumsum(), rsuffix="_deduction").merge(
    df2, on="name"
)

out["amount_remaining"] = out["amount_paid"] - out["amount_deduction"]

out["amount_used"] = np.where(
    out["amount_remaining"] > 0,
    out["amount"],
    (out["amount"] + out["amount_remaining"]).clip(lower=0),
)

out['amount_left'] = out['amount'] - out['amount_used']
out[['name', 'amount', 'amount_used', 'amount_left']]
```