# Python: Deduct values from DataFrame based on cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame 1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'virat', 'rohit', 'rohit'],
    'amount': [1000, 500, 200, 500, 150, 120, 100]})
```

and DataFrame 2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['virat', 'rohit'],
    'amount_paid': [1400, 300]})
```

Name in dataframe2 is unique. Using amount_paid column in df2. start deducting value in ascending order and stop once amount_paid in df2 is completely utilized.

If there is a extra amount in add in a new column amount_extra

expected output:

```
    name    amount_left   amount_used_to_knock_off      amount_extra
0   virat   0                1000                          0
1   virat   100               400                          0
2   virat   200                 0                          0
3   virat   500                 0                          0
4   virat   150                 0                          0
5   rohit   0                 120                          0
6   rohit   0                 100                         80
```

What we have tried (using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284431/16343464)):

```
s = (df1
 .groupby('name')['amount'].cumsum()
 .sub(df1['name'].map(df2.set_index('name')['amount_paid']))
)

df1['amount_left'] = df1['amount'].mask(s.lt(df1['amount']), s.clip(lower=0))

df1['amount_used_to_knock_off'] = (df1['amount'].sub(s).clip(lower=0)
                                   .mask(s<0, df1['amount'])
                                   )
```

Output:

```
    name  amount  amount_left  amount_used_to_knock_off
0  virat    1000            0                      1000
1  virat     500          100                       400
2  virat     200          200                         0
3  virat     500          500                         0
4  virat     150          150                         0
5  rohit     120            0                       120
6  rohit     100            0                       100
```

Need help on getting the amount_extra data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add the extra amount in the last row per name if anything is left, use [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html), [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df1['amount_extra'] = ((-s).clip(lower=0)
                       .mask(df1['name'].duplicated(keep='last'), 0)
                      )
```

Output:

```
    name  amount  amount_left  amount_used_to_knock_off  amount_extra
0  virat    1000            0                      1000             0
1  virat     500          100                       400             0
2  virat     200          200                         0             0
3  virat     500          500                         0             0
4  virat     150          150                         0             0
5  rohit     120            0                       120             0
6  rohit     100            0                       100            80
```

If you remove the mask, you'll get the amount left after each payment is made:

```
    name  amount  amount_left  amount_used_to_knock_off  amount_extra
0  virat    1000            0                      1000           400
1  virat     500          100                       400             0
2  virat     200          200                         0             0
3  virat     500          500                         0             0
4  virat     150          150                         0             0
5  rohit     120            0                       120           180
6  rohit     100            0                       100            80
```